# C++ print progress with minimal impact on runtime

Tags: c++, console, progress

I have a C++ program with a long running loop. It has about 500000 iterations. 
I'd like to print the progress every 5%.

What I have so far is below.
Problem with this is that it will keep writing the same line (0%, %5 etc) over and over. This is because after truncating the percent to an integer there are 1000's of iterations that will hit upon a multiple of 5. This makes the program noticeably slower.

Conversely, if I don't truncate to an integer, then the result of `percent % 5.0` is unlikely to be precisely 0.

How can I print a progress indicator with the minimum possible impact on runtime?

```
// Counters for progress indicator
int i = 0;
float totalWindows = (float)(win.nX * win.nY);
int percent;

while (win.next() == 0)
{
    // Read the data

    // Nicely formatted progress indicator
    i++;
    percent = (i / totalWindows) * 100;
    if (percent % 5 == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "\r" << std::string(percent/5, '|') << percent << "%";
        std::cout.flush();
    }



}
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers. I have gone with christophes' which just came to the least number of instructions.
It shaved 25% of runtime, so pretty significant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that `totalWindows` seems to remain unchanged, and `integer` increments/decrements will probably be faster than a lot of `double` operations with conversion to int,  I propose:

```
// Counters for progress indicator
int i = 0;
float totalWindows = (float)(win.nX * win.nY);
int increment5 = 0.05 * totalWindows; // how many iterations does 5% represent ? 
int countdown = increment5;   // decrement countdown instead of modulo
int percent5 = 0;  // number of elements in the progress bar (1 means 5%)

while (win.next() == 0)
{
    // Read the data

    // Nicely formatted progress indicator
    i++;
    if (--countdown == 0)
    {
            percent5++;
            std::cout << "\r" << std::string(percent5, '|') << percent5*5 << "%";
            countdown = increment5;  
            std::cout.flush();
    }

}
```

If you fear that the cumulative roundings would not be acceptable for displaying the progress, you could always opt to calculate the exact value in the `if`-block:  the calculation would be performedonly once every 5% instead of at each iteration.

Comment: totalWindows remains unchanged, yes. Clever solution, I like the use of the countdown

Comment: @Christophe - I think there is a minor problem in your code. The `cout`uses a string fill constructor using the variable `percent`which isn't part of your code. Maybe you want `percent5*5` instead.

Comment: @StillLearning exact !  Thanks, I've edited the answer :-).  By the way, to avoid alloc/dealloc of temporary string, one could consider creating a string variable outside the loop, reserve enough capacity for it, and every interation add a '|' at the end of the string. But this improvement would be minor as this code is only executed 20 times.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
int step = 5;
int nextPrint = step;

while (win.next() == 0)
{
    // Read the data

    // Nicely formatted progress indicator
    i++;
    percent = (100 * i) / totalWindows;
    if (percent >= nextPrint)
    {
        std::cout << "\r" << std::string(percent/5, '|') << percent << "%";
        std::cout.flush();
        nextPrint += step;
    }
}
```

BTW:
Why do you have totalWindows as a float? That also hurts performance. If the number of iterations are 500000 an 32 bit int should be sufficient.

Another and better approach because percent isn't calculated in every loop:

```
const int percentPrint = 5;
int step = totalWindows / (100/percentPrint);
int nextPrint = step;

while (win.next() == 0)
{
    // Read the data

    // Nicely formatted progress indicator
    i++;
    if (i >= nextPrint)
    {
        percent = (100 * i) / totalWindows;
        std::cout << "\r" << std::string(percent/percentPrint , '|') << percent << "%";
        std::cout.flush();
        nextPrint += step;
    }
}
std::cout << "\r" << std::string(100/percentPrint , '|') << percent << "%";
std::cout.flush();
```

Comment: Yes, this is nice, a much better approach than mine, while remaining as clear & simple

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating the percentage each time, you can calculate what 5% of the total is and use this directly.

Consider this simplified example:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv) {
  int total = 50000;
  int total_percent_stop = total * 5 / 100; //Set the percentage here.

  for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    if (i % total_percent_stop == 0) {
      printf("%d percent done\n", (i / total_percent_stop) * 5);
    }
  }
}
```

If the performance of this particular code is very important to you, you can avoid the relatively expensive division operations by doing something like this (at the expense of some readability).

```
int main(int argc, char * argv) {
  int total = 50000;
  int total_percent_stop = total * 5 / 100; //Set the percentage here

  for (int i = 0, percent_counter = 0, n_percent = 0;
       i < total;
       i++, percent_counter++) {
    if (percent_counter == total_percent_stop) {
      percent_counter = 0;
      n_percent++;
      printf("%d percent done\n", n_percent * 5);
    }
  }
}
```

On my machine, for sufficiently large values of total the second is significantly faster.  When I changed everything to unsigned long longs and set total to 5 billion, the second took 9.336 seconds and the first took 40.159 seconds